# Как правильно подобрать RAM для ноутбука

Tags: железо, ram

Как правильно подобрать плашку для ноутбука? В ноуте с завода стоит: 4 gb распаяны на плате + 4 gb стоят плашкой, которую можно заменить. Максимально поддерживаемый объем 16 гб, на нее и пал выбор. Исходные данные следующие:

[image: RAM info]

из этого понятно, какую выбрать частоту, формат и форм-фактор.

Непонятно две вещи, какие выбрать тайминги (где-то читал, что их можно поменять/настроить), и какой должен быть вольтаж у покупной плашки, варьируются от 1.15v до 1.3v.

Comment: В апгрейде был бы смысл, если бы все 8 гб, были распаяны при свободном слоте.

Answer (score 0):

старайся подбирать под расспаянную в плате, чтобы не было конфликтов. На ноуте особо не погоняешь плашки, питание ноутовское не вывезет, если это конечно не какой-нибудь ROG or Alineware. Возьмешь похожую по частотам и таймингам но 16 гб не пожалеешь!

Comment: Естественно если меньше напряжение тем лучше, но твоя материнская плата должна поддерживать его! Лучше в чем? В том что она меньше греется, меньше тратит энергии по эффективности нет разницы от 1.3V

Comment: Все верно. Разницы нет, частоты те же и тайминги точно такие же